# Security for studio monitors

Tags: studio-monitors, studio-design

I hope this is not off topic, but I'm not sure which stack exchange community would be the best place to ask this type of question.

I teach music production at a high school and we just bought some fairly expensive studio monitors. We don't want them "walking away". What would be the best way to secure them?

Comment: Do they have kensington security slots?

Comment: No, there aren't any slots like that unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill, but you can use the same security cables you'd use with a laptop or anything with the Kensington security slots, but instead of relying on the slots, you'd install the same fastener points on the speakers as you will to the desk.

[Targus Security Plates](https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Targus-security-plate-Trade-Compliant/218517.aspx?RecommendedForEDC=2492972&RecoType=RP&cm_sp=Product-_-Session&ProgramIdentifier=3)

I'm sure there are other options, and ones that may involve either stronger hardware or cheaper, or less conspicuous... but either way, chain them down if you have to.